# Please explain this bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
For /f "skip=2 tokens=2,4 delims=:()" %%G in ('powercfg -list') do (
 Powercfg -setAcValueIndex %%G sub_buttons sButtonAction 0
 if "%%H" == " *" Powercfg -setActive %%G
 )
```

Can someone please explain this to me?

I know it's changing the powercfg for a Windows PC. but dont know what it means.

Comment: `for /?` from a command prompt will explain the first line. From there you should be able to figure out most of the rest.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain where the values %%G and %%H are obtained?

Comment: `%%G` is the variable created by the `for` statement in the first line of the batch file. `%%H` is the second token in the output produced (which would be followed by `%%I`, `%%J`, and so forth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tokens=2,4` option of  the `for` command assigns the variables `%G`, `%H`.  Quoting from the documentation:

> tokens=x,y,m-n
>   Specifies which tokens from each line are to be passed to the **`for`** body for each iteration. As a result, ***additional*** variable names are allocated. The *m-n* form is a range, specifying the *m*th through the *n*th tokens. If the last character in the `tokens=` string is an asterisk (*), an additional variable is allocated and receives the remaining text on the line after the last token that is parsed.

The script reads a report from `powercfg` and looks for certain information, sets one of the profiles to *active*.  As suggested, taking it apart step-by-step would be a good exercise.

Here's a picture showing someone's power configuration:

[image]

By using colon and parentheses for delimiters, the parser ignores those (treats them as a gap), so the script would pick (allowing for column-counts...) the one ending with `*` ("High performance" in the picture).  Your picture may differ, of course.

Further reading:

- [for](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx) - Runs a specified command for each file in a set of files.
- [powercfg](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748940%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) - control power settings and configure computers to default to Hibernate or Standby modes